# PHP / difference between 2 float returns a very big result

Tags: php

I have a strange behavior when try to compute a result ...

In my app, I have an `Invoice` object with a property `totalIncludingTax` and another `unpaidAmount`.

When a payment is settled, The `unpaidAmount` property is recomputed.

Consider an invoice with a total including tax of `14.35`

**This returns** `returns double(14.35)`

```
$invoice->getTotalIncludingTax()
```

**This assertion returns** true

```
$this->assertEquals($invoice->getUnpaidAmount(), ($invoice->getTotalIncludingTax() - 14.35));
```

**BUT this dump returns** `double(1.7763568394003E-15)`

```
var_dump(($invoice->getTotalIncludingTax() - 14.35));
```

Any idea ?

**Edit**

This assertion returns true too

```
$this->assertEquals(0, ($invoice->getTotalIncludingTax() - 14.35));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.7763568394003E-15` isn't a big number, it's actually very very small. It's being shown in scientific notation; it's 0.0000000000000017763568394003 in normal form. This is the error due to floating point representations.

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.comparison) states you should compare floats as such:

> To test floating point values for equality, an upper bound on the
>   relative error due to rounding is used. This value is known as the
>   machine epsilon, or unit roundoff, and is the smallest acceptable
>   difference in calculations.
>
> `$a` and `$b` are equal to 5 digits of precision.

```
<?php
$a = 1.23456789;
$b = 1.23456780;
$epsilon = 0.00001;

if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon) {
    echo "true";
}
?>
```

Perhaps the `assertEquals` does something similar

Comment: thanks for your answer but this assertion `$this->assertEquals(0, ($invoice->getTotalIncludingTax() - 14.35));` shouldn't returns true right ?

Comment: It might be that assert equals has a special case for floating point numbers where if they are close enough, it considers them equal. I've updated my answer

Comment: Ok, but how to explain that `$invoice->getTotalIncludingTax() - 14.35` returns `1.7763568394003E-15` and `14.35 - 14.35` returns 0 ? The value of the `totalIncludingTax` property is exactly `14.35`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's returning exactly that value? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4fd13a2048218d85e8cd1991f5944551bf50afe4 seems to think it's 0

Comment: Damn, I cannot reproduce this case in a sandbox ... I'm just sure that `var_dump($invoice->getTotalIncludingTax())` returns `double(14.35)`. I'm using php 5.5.13

Answer (score 0):

I would always prefer to do calculations/comparision in bcmath with the scale of 4 and then round it with the scale of 2 or 0.

check http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php